# Cannot change datetime in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have the following csv data:

```
sep=;
ACCELEROMETER X (m/s²);ACCELEROMETER Y (m/s²);ACCELEROMETER Z (m/s²);GRAVITY X (m/s²);GRAVITY Y (m/s²);GRAVITY Z (m/s²);LINEAR ACCELERATION X (m/s²);LINEAR ACCELERATION Y (m/s²);LINEAR ACCELERATION Z (m/s²);GYROSCOPE X (rad/s);GYROSCOPE Y (rad/s);GYROSCOPE Z (rad/s);LIGHT (lux);MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT);MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT);MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT);ORIENTATION Z (azimuth °);ORIENTATION X (pitch °);ORIENTATION Y (roll °);PROXIMITY (m);ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa);TEMPERATURE (C);RELATIVE HUMIDITY (%);SOUND LEVEL (dB);LOCATION Latitude : ;LOCATION Longitude : ;LOCATION Altitude ( m);LOCATION Altitude-google ( m);LOCATION Altitude-atmospheric pressure ( m);LOCATION Speed ( m/s);LOCATION Accuracy ( m);LOCATION ORIENTATION (°);Satellites in range;Time since start in ms ;YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS
0.2825;0.3932;10.0299;-0.219;2.4781;9.4859;0.5052;-2.0443;0.5388;0.0699;0.0215;0.0045;18.0;43.3;-52.23;64.99;213.54;-15.07;1.18;8.0;1023.4;23.0;63.3;61.013;32.06071;34.775364;;29.3243923;;;30.0;;0 / 0;6;2015-12-07 20:51:06:608
0.6422;-0.5429;10.076;-0.023;1.4988;9.6914;0.7552;-1.3062;-0.0186;0.0046;0.0582;0.1172;19.0;43.6;-51.87;70.25;215.0;-9.66;-0.18;8.0;1023.37;23.0;63.3;41.656;32.06071;34.775364;;29.3243923;;;30.0;;0 / 0;1007;2015-12-07 20:51:07:609
```

and when i'm trying to use the command:

```
data['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(data['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

I'm getting the following error:

> KeyError: 'YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'

What is wrong?
(I'm new to Python, but I can't figure it out)

Comment: What is `df.info()` ? If you create `df` by `read_csv`, what is `csv`? can you add 2,3 rows of your `csv` to question?

Comment: I've added the first part of the csv file. Thanks

Comment: Super, there is problem. you have to skip first line of csv, give me time, I add answer.

Comment: Hmmm, it seem you bad copy `csv`, becasue it contains `/`. Or file contains `/`?  Can you copy from file directly? Or if is possible, you can share file ?.

Comment: Yes no problem: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09733748244932573806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add parameter `skiprows=1` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for skipping first line of `csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('university.csv', sep=";", skiprows=1)
```

Then you can convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                               format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Or you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `parse_dates` and `date_parser`:

```
import pandas as pd

dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
df = pd.read_csv('university.csv', 
                 sep=";", 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 parse_dates=['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'],
                 date_parser=dateparse)

print df.head()
```